# Django startswith unicode

Tags: database, django, unicode

Is it possible to get `Author.objects.filter(surname__istartswith='Z')` return results that also start with 'Ž', 'Ź' etc.?

The only solution that comes into my mind is to flatten `surname` with unicode transliteration and save it as `surname_flat` in db. Then `Author.objects.filter(surname_flat__istartswith='Z')` would work, but it requires database migration.

I'm using postgres.

Comment: Your approach is the one that I would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [django-unaccent](https://github.com/djcoin/django-unaccent/) library has been written to provide the functionality you require.

By doing this however you are making your solution database-dependent, which may be an issue if you decide to move database engines in future.

Your solution to add an additional calculated column is the one that I would use, as this keeps your code db-independent. You can also index your column more effectively.  Because the django-unaccent library uses a database-function-based search, it will do a column scan of your data every time you use it.

Comment: Thank you, this is robust solution, however database migration is less pain in my case, I will use calculated column approach.